# input value is undefined from form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to access form data using GET method but it is giving me undefined.

URL: GET /search?email=dsdsd%40gmail.com

In my view I am creating form as:

```
          // search.jade
         // register form
                form(method='GET' action='/search')
                    div.form-group
                    label(for='email') Email:
                    input#favoriteBook.form-control(type='email', placeholder='' name='email' required)
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Search
```

And in my app.js:

```
                app.get('/search',function(req,res){ // Performing search
                console.log(req.body.email); // getting UNDEFINED 
                loadSchema.find({email: req.body.email},function(err,users){
                    res.render('list',{users: users});
                });
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question. Follow guidelines of stackoverflow in order to receive better response. Don't add irrelevant tags and code in question. First describe your issue, than explain what you have done than. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access query string parameter from `req.query` object. So, you can get email property value at `req.query.email`. For more information about req.query, check http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query. Please change to the following in your app.js

```
 app.get('/search',function(req,res){ // Performing search
   console.log(req.query.email); // prints email value
   loadSchema.find({email: req.query.email},function(err,users){
     res.render('list',{users: users});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the body of the GET request, but the GET request does not have a body to access the body you would have to use a POST request, but since you are sending the value as a query string param, in your express code you can catch it this way:

```
app.get('/search',function(req,res){ // Performing search
            console.log(req.params.email); // no UNDEFINED 
            loadSchema.find({email: req.params.email},function(err,users){
                res.render('list',{users: users});
            });
        });
```

The query string params go under `req.params.attributeName`

Comment: I changed method name of form to POST and body with params. its not solved the issue and the value is not being written into the console.